# android Live Wallpaper Water Ripple Effect

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I want to use water ripple effect in my application,which effect continue in touch area repeatedly.
Can any one please help me ,to implement live water ripple effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of a touch ripple effect here:

https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliExamples

It utilizes the rajawali OpenGL ES framework/library. You can download the rajawali examples app from the market to see how it looks. Browse through the "src" folder and you will see the TouchRippleEffect activity and renderer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have downloaded, but the TouchRippleEffect activity can not be used